# Issue connecting to PHPDebug on VSCode ( in my host ) from docker container ( Xdebug ) inside a Oracle VirtualBox VM

Tags: php, docker, vagrant, xdebug

I have a Vagrant manager managing an Oracle VirtualBox VM ( Ubuntu ). There is a docker container inside this VM. The Docker container has a PHP interpreter and I need to debug this PHP program running inside the container using Xdebug.

I am running the Vagrant from my Windows PC ( HOST ). I am using VSCode as the IDE in my host to connect to Xdebug in the docker container.

Here are my Xdebug settings in xdebug.ini:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remove_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_host= <vagrant pvt n/w ip>
xdebug.remote_port=9001
```

Here is my VSCode launch.json settings:

```json
"name": "Listen for XDebug",
"type": "php",
"request": "launch",
"pathMappings": {
    "/core": "e:/core"
},
"port": 9001,
"log": true
```

I have forwarded the port 9001 in my Vagrant File. Also did the port mapping 9001:9001 in my docker compose yaml file.

Comment: You need your host's IP and not Vagrant's. PHP needs to open a connection to the IDE and it is on your host.

Comment: @AleksanderWons: I tried giving Host IP also, It connects. But, XDebug is not detecting the breakpoints. Any idea, How to give the Host IP? It cant be 127.0.0.1 ( because we are in the conainters context now ). I did ipconfig/all in my host. There are 2 interfaces present for Vagrant and wifi adapter. I tried with all those 3 IPs. It connects, but it doesnt identify the breakspoints.

Comment: Which Xdebug version are you using? You're using xdebug 2 settings, but... I would be surprised if you were not using Xdebug 3 yet, and if you don't... you should.

Comment: And what do xdebug logs tell you? Is xdebug really able to connect to the IDE?

Comment: @Derick: Its an existing VM and Docker settings that I am working on. Its PHP 7.0 and XDEBUG 2 still. Pls find "php -v" output below   ::                                                                                     
PHP 7.0.32-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct  1 2018 11:45:35) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.32-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans

Comment: @AleksanderWons: Xdebug logs below::  Log opened at 2022-07-07 08:20:16
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 10.143.8.177:9001.
I: Connected to client. :-)

Comment: -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///qalma/core/artisan" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.0.27-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1" protocol_version="1.0" appid="23221"><engine version="2.6.0"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2018 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Comment: These logs keep coming in a loop.

Comment: @Harish The one thing I've noticed so far is: Xdebug breaks for `/qalma/core/artisan` file .. but your path mapping only has `/core`. As far as I'm concerned, that script will be outside of the mapped path and such a request should be ignored by VSCode/PHP Debugger).

Comment: @LazyOne: Thanks for the response. Tried with the following mapping                                   "pathMappings": {
                "/qalma/core": "e:/qalma/core"
            } ................ Its the same result

Comment: I'm not using Windows, but is it really `e:/qalma/core`, or should it be `e:\qalma\core`?